# Find $E[X]$ when $E[aX] = b$ where $E$ is the Expectation.

Tags: probability, expected-value

I know how to calculate the Expectation of random variable. But how to find the $E[X]$ when $E[aX] = b$ where $a$ and $b$ are some positive constants?

Comment: The question does not make sense. When $a=b=1$ the hypothesis says nothing. How can you find $EX$ without any information?

Comment: The question is poorly phrased but $a,b$ are not supposed to be chosen freely. I think it means :  if you know the value of $E[a^X]$ for some $a>0$, can you compute $E[X]$ ? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @nicomezi You cannot. Unless you know $Ea^{x}$ for all $a>0$ there is no hope.

Comment: Then put that into an answer. I did not claim it is true, but it does make sense (in a way).

Comment: It makes sense when a for some positive value makes a known expansion after a^X. Lets say for a =2 it makes the binomial expansion and then the expectation is sum of its inner terms = b.

Comment: @nicomezi Does my answer clear up the doubts?

Comment: It does (I did the +1).

Comment: The answer to the question as stated now is $E[X]=b/a$

Comment: Indeed. Please can you check your post again, do you really mean $E[aX]$ ? @Anonymous

Answer (score 1):

There is no $a>0$ such that the value of  $Ea^{X}$ determines the value of $EX$. To prove this I will demonstrate that there exist random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $Ea^{X}=Ea^{Y}$ but $EX \neq EY$.

I will leave the trivial case $a=1$ to you.

Let $X=0$ and $Y$ take the values $\pm 1$ with probabilites $\frac  1 {1+a}$ and $\frac a {1+a}$ respectively. Then $Ea^{Y}=a\frac  1 {1+a}+\frac 1 a \frac  a {1+a}=1=Ea^{X}$. But $EX=0$ and $EY=\frac  1 {1+a} -(1-\frac  1 {1+a})=\frac {1-a} {1+a} \neq EX$.